# Pressing $ then Enter adds a newline before the last character, not after

Tags: vi

I'm trying to add another line at the end of the last line in the VI editor and I need to go to the very last of the last line (command $) to insert a new line by hitting the enter key. But the cursor stays on the last character: if I have to hit enter on this last character, it makes the *last* character of the last line go to the *next* line. That is not what I need. I just need to insert a line by hitting the enter key.

Operating system: Solaris X11

Comment: `o` will open a newline regardless of where the cursor is on the current line

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Thanks Hunter McMillen, that is exactly what i'm looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`e` is used to go to end of word.  You should use `$` to go to end of line.

You can insert another line from the current position by using `o` (for open).

You can also use `A` to append something to the end of line from anywhere on the line.

Comment: How do I go to the end of the word, ie., if I do $ it will go to the end but cursor stays on the last char, I cannot go to the next spot after the char

Comment: There is nothing after the last character.  So, you can use `a` to append after the current character, or `A` to append at the end of line.

Comment: Excellent! thank you. I'll mark it answered

Answer (score 4):

1. The normal way to add a new line (or new lines) below the current line
   is to type `o` (**o**pen). 
   It will *immediately* create a new, blank line,
   so you don't need to type <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   (until/unless you want to add two or more lines).
2. Are you using `i` (**i**nsert)? 
   To add text *after* the current position, use `a` (**a**ppend). 
   Or, to add text at the end of the current line, use `A`,
   which is effectively short for `$a`.

Comment: My bad, i changed the question, I was using $ instead of e.

Comment: I think it's a custom .vimrc; we had a shared "base" one at work for new hires that did the same thing, where [enter] in normal mode was mapped to [i][enter][esc]